# How can I import module exported functions into the global scope for HTML onclick="" event-handlers?

Tags: javascript, module, systemjs

A simple HTML webpage using SystemJS 0.21 that's loading a JavaScript module compiled from TypeScript. The HTML web-page has an `onclick=""`-style event-handler that calls a function declared in a module file:

### tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "system",
        "moduleResolution": "node"
    }
}
```

### Page.ts

```
export function onButtonClick( e: Event, btn: HTMLButtonElement ): boolean {

    console.log( 'clicked!' );
    return true;
}
```

I'm using SystemJS in a HTML page in a website (not an SPA) like so:

### system.config.js

```
System.config( {

    map: { /* ... */ },

    packages: {
        '/scripts/': { defaultExtension: 'js' }
    }

} );

System.import( '/scripts/Page' );
```

### Page.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="/scripts/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/system.config.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <button onclick="onButtonClick( event, this )">Click me and check the browser console</button>

</body>
</html>
```

This doesn't work because the `onButtonClick` function is defined in `Page.js` as a function within the module, which means it is not imported as a property into the global (`Window`) object in consuming scripts. So I get this output in my console window:

> Uncaught `ReferenceError`: `onButtonClick` is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (Page.html:8)

So how can I get my `<button onclick="onButtonClick( event, this )"` to use the `function onButtonClick` in `Page.ts`/`Page.js`?

Answer (score 0):

I developed a workaround solution for now:

1. Extend the global `Window` object interface in the TypeScript module to add the new global functions.
2. Assign those declared function properties on `window` within the module's "top-level" function.

This isn't the same thing as having SystemJS importing a module *into* the `window` object (which is what I originally wanted) and this approach also requires me to modify the module I'm importing, but it works for now.

Like so:

### Page.ts

```
declare global {
    declare interface Window {
        onButtonClick( e: Event, btn: HTMLButtonElement ): boolean;
    }
}

function onButtonClick( e: Event, btn: HTMLButtonElement ): boolean {

    console.log( 'clicked!' );
    return true;
}

window.onButtonClick = onButtonClick;
```

The `onButtonClick` function no-longer needs to be exported. And this can be made even more succinct by just assigning the function directly:

### Page.ts

```
declare global {
    declare interface Window {
        onButtonClick( e: Event, btn: HTMLButtonElement ): boolean;
    }
}

window.onButtonClick = onButtonClick( e: Event, btn: HTMLButtonElement ): boolean {

    console.log( 'clicked!' );
    return true;
};
```

Because the `Page.ts`/`Page.js` module is loaded asynchronously it does mean that when `Page.html` loads the `onclick=""` attributes won't work until the module is loaded - but assuming that happens quickly after the page loads there won't be any user-experience issues.